# Issue in reusing table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My custom cell contains many ui elements. I found it very difficult to reuse cells.So i set the cell created to nil in the didEndDisplayingCell delegate method of table view. Is there any issue in doing so. will it hamper performance. This is my code

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows indexOfObject:indexPath] == NSNotFound){
         VBMerchantDealCell *cell = (VBMerchantDealCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
         cell = nil;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the cell to nil? Why aren't you using the re-use mechanism? Maybe if you explain what the problem you are having is somebody might be able to assist you.

Comment: @Abizern My custom cell contains toggle badges which switches every 3 sec. The text that is displayed on badge while toggling are different also the the badge color and text that displayed on every badge on a cell is different. how do i handle this. When i tried to use same cell with reuse enabled, the contents and text inside cell are duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not reusing cells will be very bad for performance. Also using transparency in your cells is likely to affect performance (i.e. Scrolling). You can use instruments or the simulator to check for this: 'color blended layers' will color all non-opaque views as red.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `prepareToReuse` method in your cell subclass. Here reset all the values to default and in the corresponding `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method set the appropriate values to cell.

And ya, not reusing the cell is an unnecessary performance overhead.

Comment: @Adhithya
Here my custom cell contains the badge and a label inside that badge (both in xib). Then how can i reuse the cell. If i make the cell.imgBadgeImageView.image = nil and cell.lblBadgeLabel.Text = nil both of them will disappear from all the remaining cells(as we are reusing the cells). Do i need to add this as sub view to the cell from code. If i do so how can i access the cell badge image view and badge label. I need to access these two because there is a animation (for imageview) and text change (for label).
Plz respond...

Comment: I have already answered that. After you deque the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, set the correct values to you badge imageview and cell.